# __dirname is not defined in Node.js 10 experimental?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js 10.0.0 & my `index.mjs` looks like:

```js
import path from "path";

console.log(__dirname);
```

In my terminal, I run

```js
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

And I get the following error:

```
(node:3750) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
at file:///MyFolderPath/node-10/index.mjs:3:21
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:106:14)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ESM is not node-specific, and node-specific "globals" (such as `__dirname` and module) will not work. [`import.meta`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) is expected to provide a suitable replacement.

Source: GitHub [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/16844).

Answer (score 1):

ES6 modules don't define `__dirname`. You can define it yourself using code like this below. This assumes a filesystem context, not a browser.

```
import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
```

See `import.meta` in the [node reference](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#importmetaurl) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) for specifics.