# __dirname is not defined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

So I have an app that I am making that has a React front-end and Node-express back-end. For some reason when I access the variable `__dirname` in any way, it says it is undefined even though intelesense can detect it.

index.js

```js
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import chalk from "chalk";
import path from "path";

const PORT = process.env.PORT,
app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app),
log = console.log;

console.log(__dirname);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "client", "build"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.js"));
});

server.listen(PORT, function () {
    log(chalk.green("Listening on PORT:"), PORT);
});
```

Terminal output

> (node:29852) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
> file:///home/david/Downloads/coding/PWA/React/startup/meter-detection-startup/index.js:11
> console.log(__dirname);
> ^

> ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
> at file:///home/david/Downloads/coding/PWA/React/startup/meter-detection-startup/index.js:11:13
> at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:139:37)
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_dirname is not defined in Node.js 10 experimental?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268077/dirname-is-not-defined-in-node-js-10-experimental)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it does, thank you very much