# __dirname or __base is not defined in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my server.js file,

```
global.__base = __dirname;
require(__base + '/app/init/cronjob');
```

These two properties are defined. It works fine.

While inside cronjob.js,

Upon using `__base` for anything, it says that it is undefined.

The program itself runs fine but the vscode debugger has problem finding `__base`, how do I tackle this?

Comment: Is __dirname throwing or is __base throwing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_dirname is not defined in Node.js 10 experimental?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268077/dirname-is-not-defined-in-node-js-10-experimental).  In the future please SO before asking a question.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK, __base is throwing the error in my case.

Comment: @Inigo, It does not answer. Hence I posted.

Comment: I'd throw too, maybe stop using __base...?

Comment: require(__dirname + '/app/init/cronjob'); should be supported better if used by itself.

Comment: This does not look like ES6 module usage. I've removed the tags.

Comment: Are you sure that `global` is the global object? Can you show the code of your *cronjob.js* file? Is this the first time the module is required, or was it cached already?